# nuxt i18n routing not working for sub pages

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, nuxt.js, vue-i18n, nuxt-i18n

I have changed my app to make it work with nuxt i18n and the translation seems to work when I access the routes directly.

E.g. `http://localhost:3000/fr/step/1`

I have the following structure in my app and each step is one page with different components inside.

[image]

My nuxt config:

[image]

In the documentation it says I need to add `localePath` for my nuxt-links to make it work with the i18n plugin.
https://nuxt-community.github.io/nuxt-i18n/basic-usage.html#nuxt-link

For example:

```
<nuxt-link to="localePath('about')">About</nuxt-link>
```

In my app I used to navigate to the next step programmatically like:

```
this.$router.push({ path: `step/${this.currentStep + 1}` });
```

Now I have two problems (questions):

1. How would I navigate to the route programmatically with `localePath`? For example `this.localePath('step/2')` doesn't work. It redirects always to the frontpage.
2. Why is it not working with a normal link in the template? I have tested this:
   `<nuxt-link :to="localePath('step/2')">Foo</nuxt-link>` but it also doesn't work. When I try something like: 
    `<nuxt-link :to="localePath('success')">Foo</nuxt-link>` it works because the `success` page is on the first level.

It seems that there is something wrong in the routing or the way I handle the subpages. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I can work well according to this [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/nuxt/nuxt.js/tree/dev/examples/i18n?from-embed)

Comment: But isn't that something nuxt is handling automatically? In this example, there is always a duplicate for each page. Also the i18n is loaded as plugin instead of a nuxt module. The links are also different e.g. `<NuxtLink :to="$i18n.path('about')"`...

Answer (score 6):

Below worked for me. I have a Nuxt pages structure like this.

```
/pages/settings/car-form.vue
```

This is the Nuxt link to this sub-page with the working `localePath()`. Note the **missing slash** below in the path.

```html
<nuxt-link :to="localePath({ name: 'settings-car-form' })">Car form</nuxt-link>
```

As the [Nuxt docs suggest](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#basic-routes): you have to link to the (Nuxt) route `name`. **Slashes in the path become a dash**. See the `routes` array on the [documentation page](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing#basic-routes).

You can lookup the `name` of the Nuxt routes of your project in the Nuxt generated  `.nuxt/routes.json` -file. There you'll find your routes with a `__en` (for english, or `__de` for German) suffixes added to the `name` property. Point the above `localePath()` to that name WITHOUT the `__en` suffix (like in my example above).

Comment: helped alot was looking for a way to translate the nested route! .nuxt/routes.json did the trick, thanks

Answer (score 3):

Ok, think I found the solution to my problem but I'm not sure if this the correct way to do it:

To switch the route with the current locale this works for me:

```
this.$router.push({ path: this.localePath({ path: `step/${this.currentStep + 1}` }) });
```

In the template it works with:

```
<nuxt-link
  :to="localePath({ path: `step/${currentStep + 1}` })">
  Next step
</nuxt-link>
```